# Cannot find "Copy Local" option in Visual Studio 2013 for my reference assemblies

Tags: c#, xslt, visual-studio-2013, assemblies, openxml

When I publish my site I get this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Everywhere I have searched is telling me that I need to set "Copy Local" to true for that reference. However I cannot find it in Visual Studio 2013. Has that option been removed?

Comment: go to your project, click `References`, right click the dll (`DocumentFormat.OpenXml`), go to `Properties`, `Copy Local` is in the properties window.

Answer (score 0):

Select the reference you wish to modify in `Solution Explorer` and press `F4`. The properties window will pop up and `Copy Local` will be in there.